# Service Account Unable to Push Docker Image to Google Artifact Registry

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-run, service-accounts, google-artifact-registry

I am trying to `push` a Docker image to Google Artifact Registry (GAR) while impersonating a Service Account (`$SERV_ACCT_EMAIL`):

> denied: Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts" denied on resource "projects/$GCP_PROJECT_ID/locations/us-west1/repositories/$GAR_REPOSITORY" (or it may not exist)

`$SERV_ACCT_EMAIL` has Artifact Registry Writer (`roles/artifactregistry.writer`) and Artifact Registry Reader (`roles/artifactregistry.reader`) roles; the latter of which has the permission `artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts`. Thus, if the resource is granted [access to `$SERV_ACCT_EMAIL`](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#providing_credentials_to_your_application), I believe I will indeed be able to `push` those artifacts.

How do I `push` to GAR while impersonating `$SERV_ACCT_EMAIL`?

Comment: While not highly sensitive information, you _may_ want to follow [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253718) link to find out how to permanently remove your Google Cloud Project ID from your question edit history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to `configure-docker` while impersonating your service account (`$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL`):

1. Check to make sure you are still impersonating `$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL`:

   ```shell
   gcloud auth list

   #=>

   Credentialed Accounts
   ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
           . . .
   *       $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL
           . . .
   ```

   if not:

   ```shell
   gcloud auth activate-service-account \
   "$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL" \
   --key-file=$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_FILE_PATH

   #=>

   Activated service account credentials for: [$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL]
   ```
2. Run the `configure-docker` command against the `auth` group:

   ```shell
   gcloud auth configure-docker us-west1-docker.pkg.dev

   #=>

   . . .
   Adding credentials for: us-west1-docker.pkg.dev
   . . .
   ```
3. Finally, try `push`ing the Docker image again.

Comment: Im not sure about this, I think `configure-docker` does nothing more than add the `credHelper` entry in the docker config.